# How do I drop rows in a pandas dataframe based on the time of day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rows, drop

I am trying to drop specific rows in a dataframe where the index is a date with 1hr intervals during specific times of the day. (It is hourly intervals of stock market data).

For instance,  2021-10-26 09:30:00-4:00,2021-10-26 10:30:00-4:00,2021-10-26 11:30:00-4:00,  2021-10-26 12:30:00-4:00 etc.

I want to be able to specify the row to keep by hh:mm (e.g. keep just the 6:30, 10:30 data each day), and drop all the rest.

I'm pretty new to programming so have absolutely no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are datetime objects and not strings, you can do something like this

```
df = pd.Dataframe()
...input data, etc...
columns = df.columns
kept = []
for col in columns
    if (col.dt.hour == 6 or col.dt.hour == 10) and col.dt.minute == 30 
        kept.append(col)
    else:
        continue
df = df[kept]
```

see about half way down about working with time in pandas on this source here

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-datetime-tutorial/

Comment: Hi Sean, I tried to make your solution work, but couldn't (I really am a newbie!)
But I did get it to work by converting the datetime format to a string, then use str.contains to just keep the times I wanted. I'm not using the dates for anything so it didn't matter that they were converted to strings:  My dataframe is called 'data', and the column with the dates is 'Date'. The rows with 10:30 and 14:30 were ones I wanted to keep. Thanks!

    data['Date'] = data['Date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
data[(data['Date'].str.contains('10:30')) | (data['Date'].str.contains('14:30'))]

Comment: That works too, same idea!